# How do I backport if constexpr with the shortest code possible?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I'm using this code to achieve type query like in C#:

```
template<class T>
constexpr bool IsSixtyFourBit() {
    return is_same<T, int64_t>() || is_same<T, uint64_t>();
}

template<class T>
constexpr bool IsDouble() {
    return is_same<T, double>() || is_same<T, double_t>();
}

template<class T>
constexpr bool IsFloat() {
    return is_same<T, float>() || is_same<T, float_t>();
}


template<class T>
constexpr bool IsReal() {
    return IsDouble<T>() || IsFloat<T>();
}

template <class T>
constexpr T MakePseudoNumberGenerator(T min, T max) {
    if constexpr (IsSixtyFourBit<T>()) {
        mt19937_64 rng(random_device{}());            // random-number engine used (Mersenne-Twister in this case)
        uniform_int_distribution<T> uni(min, max); // guaranteed unbiased

        return uni(rng);
    } else if constexpr (IsReal<T>()) {
        mt19937_64 rng(random_device{}());            // random-number engine used (Mersenne-Twister in this case)
        uniform_real_distribution<T> uni(min, max); // guaranteed unbiased

        return uni(rng);
    } else {
        mt19937 rng(random_device{}());            // random-number engine used (Mersenne-Twister in this case)
        uniform_int_distribution<T> uni(min, max); // guaranteed unbiased

        return uni(rng);
    }
}
```

But I cannot figure out how to rewrite it for C++ environment under C++17 using the least code...partial specialization should work here but it is not that practical...

Full code: https://godbolt.org/g/QBs92V

Comment: https://medium.com/@LoopPerfect/c-17-vs-c-14-if-constexpr-b518982bb1e2
I'm still deciphering what if constexpr is doing under the hood...

Comment: You wanna rewrite it with *C++14* or what?

Comment: Not only to rewrite it with C++14, but with the shortest code ever too.

Answer (score 2):

In my understanding, the way to simulate `if constexpr` that requires the least extra machinery and syntactic changes is to use `std::tuple`. The general approach is to translate the code

```
if constexpr (P) {
    T;
} else {
    F;
}
```

into a call to one of two polymorphic lambdas encapsulating the true and false branches:

```
std::get<P ? 0 : 1>(std::forward_as_tuple(
    [&](auto) { T; },
    [&](auto) { F; }))(0);
```

This allows keeping the predicate and both branches in the same order and the same enclosing scope; it is in fact possible to put the emulation code inside a macro checking `__cplusplus` version while leaving the business logic unchanged.

Since the lambdas are polymorphic, they will be checked for syntactic correctness and will only be instantiated once `P` is evaluated.

For example, in your case:

```
template <class T>
constexpr T MakePseudoNumberGenerator(T min, T max) {
    return std::get<IsSixtyFourBit<T>() ? 0 : 1>(std::forward_as_tuple(
    [&](auto) {
        mt19937_64 rng(random_device{}());            // random-number engine used (Mersenne-Twister in this case)
        uniform_int_distribution<T> uni(min, max); // guaranteed unbiased

        return uni(rng);
    }, std::get<IsReal<T>() ? 0 : 1>(std::forward_as_tuple(
    [&](auto) {
        mt19937_64 rng(random_device{}());            // random-number engine used (Mersenne-Twister in this case)
        uniform_real_distribution<T> uni(min, max); // guaranteed unbiased

        return uni(rng);
    },
    [&](auto) {
        mt19937 rng(random_device{}());            // random-number engine used (Mersenne-Twister in this case)
        uniform_int_distribution<T> uni(min, max); // guaranteed unbiased

        return uni(rng);
    }))))(0);
}
```

Comment: That's really a big thinking outta the box. Never have I know to use a tuple for simulating a conditional! Appreciate it!